# Excel VBA - remove unmerged rows

Tags: excel, vba

Having asked a question about deleting rows with merged cells, I've got the answer below. It generated an error: Runtime error 1004: Cannot use that command on overlapping selections.

It was suggested that I should unmerge delete columns and unmerge cells and that I should start a new questions for that.  I've added the commands to delete columns and unmerge cells below. The unmerging works fine but then I get the same 1004 error again.

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim x           As Range
    Dim rngDelete   As Range

    For Each x In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If x.MergeCells Then
            If rngDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDelete = x
            Else
                Set rngDelete = Union(rngDelete, x)
            End If

        End If
    Next

    If Not rngDelete Is Nothing Then
        rngDelete.UnMerge
        rngDelete.EntireColumn.Delete
        rngDelete.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You will only be able to alter `rngDelete` once. After that you will get an error. Once `rngDelete` is `Set`, it will be treated like a constant. After you unmerge the range, it is now something new, not `rngDelete`

Comment: Notice that this will unmerge and then error out on `EntireColumn.Delete`. If you cut out the merge, this will execute `EntireColumn.Delete` and then error out on `EntireRow.Delete`. In summary, once you modify `rngDelete` like this, you can no longer simply refer to `rngDelete`

Comment: just get rid of EntireColumn.delete and you are golden.

Comment: Thanks. Works fine.